# Breaking the flow of a unit test on encounter of a certain method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I've a flow being called from the JUnit test. I need to break the flow without any errors when a method is being called and do return certain parameter from the method.

for eg.

```
breakThisMethod(String s1, String s2);
```

When the flow is being executed, I need to break the flow and terminate when the above method `breakThisMethod(..)` is encountered. Also, if possible can I get the parameters s1, s2 be returned to the test class.

Comment: What do you mean by break the flow? What is you exact goal (this question sounds like a X/Y problem)

Comment: @RC. When the method is called, I need to terminate the flow.

Comment: Is the method in question a method of a class which is mocked or spied?  f so, you could make it throw a runtime exception to halt execution - if you catch or expect the exception in the test, it will not cause the test to fail. And you could use ArgumentCaptor<String> instances to receive the value of s1 and s2. I wonder, though, if there's not a better approach to what you're trying - or a design issue (if you want to test only part of a method, why not extract that part into its own method - or class - and test it alone).  More code in your question would be useful.

Comment: if i understood ur question correctly then u have methodA which makes calls to methodB, methodC and methodD..and you want methodA to break when the call is made to methodC right?

Comment: It's like I'm triggering a method in class X and this executes a flow which includes methods from many other classes(A, B, ...). But when the control reaches to a specific method say breakThisMethod(...) in some class Z, I need to terminate and return the function params.

Comment: Most of the mocks do this by default. If you call a method unexpectedly, it throws an exception and prints the arguments provided.

Answer (score 1):

To break the flow on that method `breakThisMethod` call - you can set up a `doThrow(BreakException).when(..).breakThisMethod(..,..)` 
to throw a custom and unique exception ( lets say `BreakException` ) i.e. an exception which has not been handled in application logic chain so control returns to your test method without further execution of code.